# Multiple semicolons when using ES2015 Arrow Function Syntax in Event Listener / Assignment Statements

Tags: javascript

**TLDR:** Does the javascript community regard it as poor syntax to include a **terminating semicolon** *inside* an anonymous function inside an Event Listener / Event Assignment statement, when the terminating semicolon of the surrounding statement will be following not long after?

---

I'm currently writing a parser which reads optimised data and outputs javascript.

Generally, when the parser encounters data describing an Event Listener Statement, if an anonymous function is provided *instead of a named callback*, it will output something like the following:

**Event Listener Statement:**

```
myNode.addEventListener('click', () => {

  console.log('You clicked myNode.');

}, false);
```

Very occasionally, the data may describe an Event Assignment Statement instead:

**Event Assignment Statement:**

```
myNode.onclick = () => {

  console.log('You clicked myNode.');

};
```

---

Now, if I were *handwriting* the two examples above, I'd write them as:

**Event Listener Statement:**

```
myNode.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('You clicked myNode.'), false);
```

and

**Event Assignment Statement:**

```
myNode.onclick = () => console.log('You clicked myNode.');
```

**In Summary:** I'd not only skip the newlines, but in each case I'd also skip the curly braces (`{}`) since they're not necessary for any arrow functions implicitly returning a single statement and I'd **definitely skip** the semicolon (`;`) at the end of the single-statement anonymous arrow function.

---

And that last consideration leads to my question:

Does the javascript community regard it as poor (superfluous?) syntax to include a **terminating semicolon** inside an anonymous function inside an Event Listener / Event Assignment statement, when the terminating semicolon of the statement itself will be following not long after?

Or can I continue to allow my parser to do its own robotic thing and not worry about its grungy semi-colon-heavy style?

Comment: You're getting downvotes/close votes because you've presented us with *hypothetical* code, not code you wrote (i.e, from a project/assignment).

Comment: I'm not really understanding the difference, @Linny. Are you saying it makes a difference whether I use `.onclick` in my example above or `.onsuccess`? Because, otherwise, this _is_ code that I wrote. (Or, rather, it's code that code I wrote wrote.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semi-colons aren't necessarily required in JavaScript, and to be honest [it's a pretty divisive topic in the JS community](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion/). Having said that, I think that it is generally considered good practice to always terminate your statements. Using things such as a beautifier or minifier will typically add semi-colons into your code where necessary/missing (depending on your rules).

If you follow some popular JS code style guides; [Google's Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-semicolons-are-required), they indicate that semi-colons are required and automatic insertion is forbidden. [AirBnB's Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#semicolons) basically says the exact same thing.

**Edit:**
To clarify, I am saying that this snippet would be the "recommended" way to go, if you were to follow either of the 2 style guides that I shared.

```
myNode.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log('You clicked myNode.'); }, false);
```

You need the [braces in an arrow function, if you want to use semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501047/one-line-arrow-functions-without-braces-cant-have-a-semicolon). If you don't want to use semicolon, braces are not required for syntactic correctness.

Comment: Thanks for that. So, to clarify, are you explicitly saying that: `myNode.addEventListener('click', () => {console.log('You clicked myNode.');}, false);` is regarded as better practice than `myNode.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('You clicked myNode.'), false);`? Many thanks.

Comment: @Rounin see my update :)

Comment: Thanks again. I've bookmarked the two style guides you've linked to above. That was the confirmation I needed. Hah. That's hilarious. The parser I wrote writes better javascript than I do.